# Why stackoverflow, G+ use tables, while it's been said that tables block content to be viewed untill it downloads all the elements?

Tags: html, templates

If tables are so evil, why Stackoverflow, G+ and others use tables for their template? I've heard that tables are evil, haven't you? They block contents to be viewed in the site until they complete their structure,right?

Comment: Im not sure about the details of any browser engine out there at the moment, but most of them seem to use heuristics to avoid total blocking. That however depends in complex manner of the layout constraints applied by CSS and so on. But a simple HTML table is usually layouted and rendered while the data is still transferred if some timeout is exceed. The table usually is relayouted then several times to adapt the column with to the incoming content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least when it comes to Stack Overflow, it doesn't use tables for layout.

Tables as layout are evil when they provide the layout for *the whole site* not selected parts of it.

Stack Overflow, for instance, only uses tables for post (Questions and Answers) layout, as *part* of the page layout (which uses `div`s).

Comment: Oh goodness, I thought it's a NO, NO situation, but now things are different.

Comment: Well, it's always been the case that tables _should_ be used for _tabular_ data.